# Cannot initiate dataproc batch Serverless due to Network not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

This is a newbie question on how to properly setup the **Network Configuration** for the dataproc Serverless for Spark. From the following screenshot, I cannot find the Primary network and Subnetwork attached to this project, although to my understanding the 'default' network should be available for each project.

Can anyone shed the light on the right way to setup the network?

[image: Screenshot for the dataproc UI page]

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this issue is because [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access) is not enabled.

For Dataproc Serverless to work, Private Google Access must be enabled as referenced [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/network).

You should be able to see the network within minutes after enabling.